# I have an issue on my website (HTTP STATUS 500 - Internal Server Error)

Tags: java, debugging

[image]

Hi there, the above picture is the error I am facing through. I run Google Tag Manager then afterward, the web pages show this "HTTP error 500".

I am configuring Google Tag Manager to add a script to web pages, but then the site displays this error.

Comment: Please provide some more information, we can see only jdbc connection error

Comment: The JDBC error is presumably the problem, and not the adding of GTM?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In the log, they point out that you have some problem with JDBC, which could related to faulty database connection. Check if your database credential is correct or connection to your database is stable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know exactly the problem was but here is the link for your reference to have a  view about what's going on to my site. https://rfpproject.com/

Comment: HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.